# How to scroll a swf app using Selenium webdriver

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, flash, sikuli

**I am using:**
Eclipse Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1) - JAVA
Selenium Webdriver version 2.44.0
Sikuli (whichever version was with the 1.0.2 api)

**The Situation:**
I am working with a swf app. Content is a booklet that changes content every so often. The booklet has buttons that allow you to page/zoom. I have managed to automate the process of getting to the booklet, as well as paging and zooming. But I wish to be able to scroll up/down a page once being zoomed in on a page.
While 'normally' using the booklet you can scroll either by *dragging with the mouse*, or by using *Up/Down Arrow keys* or *Page Up/Down*.

I have tried using the following:

```
Actions scrolld = new Actions(driver);
scrolld.moveByOffset(0,-100).click();//this is to make sure the booklet is selected
scrolld.keyDown(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
scrolld.perform();
```

^this piece does nothing - I have added multiple send key commands, and I have made use of eg.: Thread.sleep(100) in between the commands.

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
           for(int second = 0;; second++)
           {
           if(second >= 3)
           {
           break;
           }
           jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,800)", "");
           System.out.println("Scrolling...");//this prints "Scrolling..." each time a scroll is done.
           Thread.sleep(3000);
           }
```

^I found and tried this piece - it scrolls on websites, but it doesn't scroll in the swf app - even after I've tried shifting focus to the element/window (even though the swf doesn't generate a new window). I wish to have it scroll incrementally, though have also tried `jse.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);");` which also does nothing.

I have also tried making use of (this is Sikuli in Eclipse) -

```
Actions build = new Actions(driver);
        build.moveByOffset(0,-100).
        clickAndHold().
        moveByOffset(0, -200).
        release().moveByOffset(0,200);//this was all typed in single line - this line-line view is for legibility.
```

^but apparently clickAndHold + moveByOffset don't work together at the moment (it's a bug or something - I can't find the link to where someone said so now).

Any and all suggestions welcome - please take note I am relatively new in this field and not as advanced as I would like to be... yet!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can look with sikuli if the scrollbar is present, and if yes. Then you click on the scrollbar and hold the mouse down. Then move the mouse up/down.

Comment: The object covers the entire screen/window and there are no scroll bars present - but thanks for the suggestion. I'm looking into Autohotkey and the likes -  will add a comment if I manage anything.